# For loops in JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

```
const animals = ["dog", "cat", "tree frog"];

function pluralize(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    array[i] += "s"
    return (array)
  }
}
console.log(pluralize(animals));
```

My goal is to create a function that adds the s to the end of words. However when I ran my code s was only added to the first word in the array. Why was the s not added to the other words in the array?

Comment: Because you immediately `return` in your loop. Move the `return` out of the loop to the end of the function.

Comment: Also you should iterate to `i < array.length`. Otherwise you will operate on `array[array.length]`, which is after the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var animals = ["dog", "cat", "tree frog"];
function pluralize(array){
  for(var i=0;i<=array.length;i++){
      array[i] += "s" ;
       } 
 return (array);
 }
```

You are returning in for loop.This is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Use return statement after loop completed.
Also loop shoud iterate from 0 to less than array.length, instead of less than and equal to.

```
function pluralize(array){
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      array[i] += "s" ;
       } 
 return (array);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `i<=array.length` to `i<array.length`.

Otherwise,it will cause infinite loop.

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i] += "s" ;

    }
   return (array)//take it outside of for loop.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your program.

1. You iterating from zero to more than the length.`i<=array.length;`.
2. You are returning inside `for loop`.

```js
const animals = ["dog", "cat", "tree frog"];
    function pluralize(array){
     for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      array[i] += "s";
     }
     return (array);
    }
 console.log(pluralize(animals));
```

The above program will return appropriate result.

Comment: I think, **tree** is not an animal but **tree frog** is.

Comment: Ok i thought you forgot comma, have changed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const animals = ["dog", "cat", "tree frog"];

function pluralize(array){
  for(var i=0;i < array.length;i++){
    array[i] += "s"
   }
  return array; 
}
   
console.log(pluralize(animals));
```

First of all, your `return` will be executed on the first loop and exited the loop, which is not what you intended, and hence moving out from loop and place at the end of function.

Second, `i <= array.length` will hit `array index outOfBound` issues. Reason is `array.length == 4` and `array[4] += "s"` is wrong as you don't have element at `array[4]`.

It's recommended to change the parameter name in your `pluralize` function from `array` to something else like `arr`, purely to improve readability because a very similar word like `Array` is a keyword/reserve word

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to use ES6/20xx, a simple `map` would do. If you want to mutate the array, use `pluralizeMutating`.

```js
const pluralize = array => array.map(v => `${v}s`);
const pluralizeMutating = array => array.forEach( (v, i) => array[i] += "s" );
let animals = ["dog", "cat", "tree frog"];
console.log(`Pluralized: [${pluralize(animals)}]`);
console.log(`animals Array is not touched: [${animals}]`);
pluralizeMutating(animals);
console.log(`pluralizeMutating ran - animals Array is now: [${animals}]`);
```

Comment: That’s not mutating. Mutating would be: `array => array.forEach( ( x, i ) => array[ i ] = pluralize( x ) )`

Comment: That wouldn't work either, but you're right (I was distracted and had to leave editing the answer). Fixed the code.